# Redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a folder 'Main' [wherein the index.php resides] with a sub-folder called 'Users'. The 'Users' folder has two sub-folders 'A' and 'B'. When **user A** logs in with correct credentials, it should show the url as `http://domain.com/A` rather than `http://domain.com/users/A`.

How can I achieve this in either .htaccess or javascript or php?

Comment: If going to `http://domain.com/A` doesn't show you the right page now, then you won't be able to change this with JavaScript. Apache configuration will be the only way to go.

Comment: This is more likely a URL rewriting question. I'll edit the tags for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you can put:

`RewriteRule ^/A$ /users/A` in .htaccess

and redirect the user via PHP (once he logs in) like this:

`header("Location: {yourSite}/A");`

Hope I understood your problem and this helps :)

Comment: @fuz3d: You're welcome!

@nikic: I'm assuming that after the login the user must be redirected to another page. If this is not the case the redirection can be left out.

Comment: +1 to @nikic. "A" users w/ Login = TRUE should just be pointed to `http://domain.com/A`. PHP has lost its job to Apache's mod_rewrite. Sending `header` is moot, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After login you need to identify if the user loging on is of type A of B
If A then redirects to '/users/A' else if it's B then redirects to '/users/B' . And this needs to be done in PHP